# COALESCE mysql trigger returning wrong value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to mysql triggers. just getting my head around things so I understand if something may not be coded correctly or the most efficient route :)

What i'm trying to do is after a database entry has been added to join the tables via values submitted to create a text string for fulltext search as I can't fulltext search across multiple tables. I can get the sentence I want by adding ,' ', after each IF statements to get the space in between values but I would prefer + space(1) because if the value is null then there would be an unnecessary space. However the + space(1) or + ' ' functions seems to throw a zero back rather than the value + a space.
The undefined action is to avoid the default value appearing in the sentence created.

Hope it makes sense, hard to explain!

my code is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tz_search_term_update` AFTER INSERT
ON `live_db`.`tz_product`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT into tz_search (listing_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
    UPDATE tz_search search
    INNER JOIN tz_product product ON search.listing_id = product.listing_id
    INNER JOIN product_data_make make ON product.make = make.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_model model ON product.model = model.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_colour colour ON product.colour = colour.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_condition cond ON product.cond = cond.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_simstatus sim ON product.sim = sim.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_spec spec ON product.spec = spec.id
    INNER JOIN product_data_capacity capacity ON product.capacity = capacity.id
    SET search.term = CONCAT(
        IF(make.make_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(make.make_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(model.model_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(model.model_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(colour.colour_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(colour.colour_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(sim.simstatus_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(sim.simstatus_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(spec.spec_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(spec.spec_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(cond.condition_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(cond.condition_name + space(1),'')),
        IF(capacity.capacity_name = 'Unspecified', '', COALESCE(capacity.capacity_name,'')))
    WHERE search.listing_id = NEW.listing_id;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` function for appending strings. Example:

```
COALESCE(CONCAT(make.make_name , space(1) ),'')
```

The operator `+` is for arithmetic operations ( `'a' + 'b'` returns `0` ).

Comment: Thank you Igor! just what I was after! Can't believe it didn't occur to me.